# Python for Motionbuilder - Add FBTree() to Qt GUI Layout

Tags: python-3.x, autodesk, shiboken2, motionbuilder

I am using Motionbuilder 2022 at the moment to build a Qt gui.
I'd like to include a Motionbuilder `FBTree` widget inside my gui but can't accomplish this with my current knowledge.

My code currently looks like this:

```
self.qtLayout = QHBoxLayout()
self.treeView = FBTree()
print("Widget address: " + str(self.treeView.GetQWidgetAddress()))
self.qtLayout.addWidget(self.treeView)
```

I get the following error/output:

```
Widget address: 0
TypeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(FBTree)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget, int = 0, PySide2.QtCore.Qt.Alignment = Default(Qt.Alignment))
  PySide2.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget)
```

And that is logical enough, the FBTree itself is not a QWidget, but it should have a QWidget as a component somewhere within its hierarchy. I know that via its inheritance of FBVisualComponent, the FBTree has a GetQWidgetAddress() command, which I expected to return a valid memory address I can Shiboken back into a QWidget object. But, this doesn't seem to be the case. I seem to always get a "0" back as the address, which doesn't seem right and definitely doesn't work when I try to wrap it back into a QWidget.

This is kind of several questions, but:
Why do I get 0 back as the address when I do `print("Widget address: " + str(self.treeView.GetQWidgetAddress()))`?
How do I access the widget for the TreeView, to add it to my layout?
Is this even the right way to approach this, or should I be trying something fundamentally different?